# SQL - Given table with three entries per day, how to write new table with one entrie per day and three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have three algorithms that run once a day at 7 AM. Each of this algorithms writes its results to a table. Namely, each algorithm writes its `Result`, the `Date` of the result and its `ID`entification. So, everyday, three lines are added to the table, like the following:

```
ID    Result    Date
A     35        21/04/2016
B     27        21/04/2016
C     31        21/04/2016
```

For enhanced reading, I now want to produce a second table where the entries for the same day are stored in the same record, like the following:

```
Date          A     B     C
21/04/2016    35    27    31
```

Can you please help?

(SQL Server 2012)

Comment: You can get those results anytime with a pivot query.  Your current plan does not account for the fact that ID = D might come up in the future.

Comment: PIVOT, PIVOT, PIVOT.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I will check the PIVOT query.

Comment: Edit: misspelled word in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo of the `PIVOT` solution for completeness of the answers. I find the `PIVOT` solution more elegant that conditional aggregation, but it comes at the cost of being less adaptable.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID CHAR(1), Result INT, Date DATE);
INSERT @T (ID, Result, Date)
VALUES ('A', 35, '2016-04-21'), ('B', 27, '2016-04-21'), ('C', 35, '2016-04-21');

SELECT  pvt.Date, pvt.A, pvt.B, pvt.C
FROM    @T AS T
        PIVOT (MAX(Result) FOR ID IN (A, B, C)) AS pvt;
```

**RESULT**

```
Date        A   B   C
-----------------------
2016-04-21  35  27  35
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot query.  You can use an explicit `pivot`.  I think conditional aggregation is easy enough:

```
select date,
       max(case when id = 'A' then result end) as a,
       max(case when id = 'B' then result end) as b,
       max(case when id = 'C' then result end) as c
from t
group by date
order by date;
```